# Failing to store keyword text field length above 32766

Tags: java, elasticsearch, keyword, maxlength

I had been trying to store a field as type keyword to support case-sensitive text search,

But when I try to store text with length above 32766 characters it is failing to store it, giving the below exception

```
    Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Document contains at least one immense term in field="case_message_message.lowcase" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[-32, -80, -84, -32, -79, -122, -32, -80, -126, -32, -80, -105, -32, -80, -77, -32, -79, -126, -32, -80, -80, -32, -79, -127, 58, 32, -32, -80, -107, -32]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 37632]
```

Is there is any way to store this text above 32766,

Elastic search version 6.1.2

Any help is really appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

This is the mapping of my index I had using a custom normalizer and also normalizer

```
{
   "org-16-database": {
      "mappings": {
         "org-16-table": {
            "properties": {
               "My field": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                     },
                     "lowcase": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                     }
                  },
                  "fielddata": true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Settings

```
    {
       "org-16-database": {
          "settings": {
             "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "org-16-database",
                "creation_date": "1521198435444",
                "analysis": {
                   "normalizer": {
                      "my_normalizer": {
                         "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                         ],
                         "type": "custom"
                      }
                   }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "lN-7iYloQWy7oaD3uMIYGQ",
                "version": {
                   "created": "6010299"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried with the type `keyword`

Comment: yes I had the type as keyword to store text field @Vijayakumar

Comment: I have pasted the link below. Can you try that. @Raviteja Gannoju

Comment: Can you post your settings of the index. It will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I had updated my question along with my mapping@Vijayakumar

Comment: Why on earth do you think you need keywords of length > 32766?

Comment: A series of unichar text was saved in a field. These were one such situation happened. If you have any suggestion please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html) when you create a new keyword field, by default is enabled the param ignore_above. This option is also useful for protecting against Lucene’s term byte-length limit of 32766. You could increase this limit modifying your mapping, without reindex. The max value allowed is 10922

Comment: When you say `You could increase this limit modifying your mapping, without reindex.` do you mean that we can change the ignore_above values?

Comment: @RavitejaGannoju yes, exactly

Comment: How do you come up with the number 10922? [The doc says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/ignore-above.html#ignore-above)
`The value for ignore_above is the character count, but Lucene counts bytes. If you use UTF-8 text with many non-ASCII characters, you may want to set the limit to 32766 / 4 = 8191 since UTF-8 characters may occupy at most 4 bytes.`

Comment: @WeihuiGuo as you can see this post was written in 2018. In previous versions of lucene a char may occupy at most 3 bytes, as written in previous versions doc:  ```The value for ignore_above is the character count, but Lucene counts bytes. If you use UTF-8 text with many non-ASCII characters, you may want to set the limit to 32766 / 3 = 10922 since UTF-8 characters may occupy at most 3 bytes.```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the Length Token filter

Vist : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html#analysis-length-tokenfilter

Comment: I don't want to tokenize the field but I have to increase the size of the field

Comment: If I use tokenize, the startswith and endswith will not work.